# SFML - Support Windows window-behaviour for borderless window

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

So I'm creating an application using SFML, which I want to be borderless, so no border style. I added the ability to move it around on the screen and am planning on adding the ability to scale the window, however, that made me realise there's just a bit more to this. When dragging any window (not mine) say to the top of the screen, windows kicks in and suggests the ability to scale it to full, or when you drag a window to the side of the screen windows, again, kicks in and suggests making it cover half your screen. And it does this on borderless applications like Google chrome, or Spotify as well. I could probably try and add this in myself, but it's obvious other applications dont implement it themselves as you can see windows actually doing it the way it visually shows it. So, how would I go ahead imlementing this? I'm using SFML 2.5.1 with C++.

I have tried looking through google and stackoverflow to see if anyone has had any similar issues, of which I couldn't find any, which could honestly have been me not knowing how exactly to phrase it.